# JavaFX: Change a DatePicker Editing Status in Table Cell based on another cell

Tags: javafx, combobox, datepicker, tableview, tablecell

I'm in this scenario:

I have a table "Visit" with a series of columns.
The table is editable and you can add more blank lines via a button.

One of the columns depends on another.
The main column has its own cellFactory to render a combobox.
The secondary column has its own cellFactory to create a date picker.

Now, the secondary cell of the table can be changed only if the cell of the main column takes one of the states of the combo box except the state "nothing"

Everything works except that I need to click each time on the secondary cell to update it in the event that the state will become "nothing."

To remedy I use the table.refresh() function in setOnEditCommit of the main column. However, if you use this function and a cell is in the "nothing" state all secondary cells become null and void.

How can I fix it?

**This is the code of the cell factory of the secondary column**

```
public class DataEditingCellVisite extends TableCell<Visite, LocalDate> {

private DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker(getDate());
private DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");

public DataEditingCellVisite() {
    datePicker.setDisable(true);
}


@Override
public void startEdit() {

  if(!this.getTableView().getItems().get(this.getTableView().getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()).getStato().equals("")) {
       datePicker.setDisable(false);
       commitEdit(datePicker.getValue());
  } else {
       datePicker.setDisable(true);
       setText(null);
       commitEdit(null);
  } 

  if (!isEmpty() && !datePicker.isDisable()) {
    super.startEdit();
    createDatePicker();
    setText(null);
    setGraphic(datePicker);
  }
}

@Override
public void cancelEdit() {
    super.cancelEdit();
    if(getDate() != null)
        setText(getDate().format(formatter));
    setGraphic(null);
}

@Override
public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    if (empty) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {
        if (isEditing()) {
            if (datePicker != null) {
               datePicker.setValue(getDate());
            }
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(datePicker);
        } else {
            setGraphic(null);
            if(datePicker.isDisable())
                setText(null);
            else
                if(getDate() != null)
                    setText(getDate().format(formatter));
        }
    }                
}

@Override
public void commitEdit(LocalDate value) {
    super.commitEdit(value);
        ((Visite)this.getTableRow().getItem()).setDataParto(value);
}

private void createDatePicker() {
    datePicker.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2);
    datePicker.setOnAction((e) -> {
        if(datePicker.getValue() != null)
            commitEdit(datePicker.getValue());
    });
    datePicker.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER || event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB) {
            if(datePicker.getValue() != null)
                commitEdit(datePicker.getValue());
        }
    });
    datePicker.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>(){
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean arg1, Boolean arg2) {
            if(!arg2) {
                if(datePicker.getValue() != null)
                    commitEdit(datePicker.getValue());
            }
        }
    });
}

private LocalDate getDate() {
    return getItem() == null ? null : getItem();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution based on this other solution
[JavaFX TableView: format one cell based on the value of another in the row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27281370/javafx-tableview-format-one-cell-based-on-the-value-of-another-in-the-row)

For anyone who needs it:

I left the table.refresh() method in CommitEdit of the main column and I changed in this way the UpdateItem method of secondary column.

```
int currentIndex = indexProperty()
                    .getValue() < 0 ? 0
                    : indexProperty().getValue();
            String type = this
                    .getTableView().getItems()
                    .get(currentIndex).getStato();
            if (type.equals("")) {
                if(getText() != null) {
                    setText(null);
                    commitEdit(null);
                }
            } else if(getDate() != null) {
                this.setText(getDate().format(formatter));
            }
```